# How to create trigger that calculate delta between two tables?

Tags: postgresql, triggers

I have three tables. I need create trigger that calculate price difference between two tables and insert it to `result` table.
Algorithm is next:
If we inserting value in `table2` we should check if `table1` have same `id`, get `start_price` from it, calculate difference, and insert result in `result` table.

For example if we are insering (assume table1 is already filled) :

```
INSERT INTO table2 VALUES (1, 135);
```

we should get in `result` table:

```
1 3.58%
```

caculation logic: 100-((135/140) * 100) = 3.58%

I can't figure out how to do this math operation inside trigger:

```
CREATE TABLE table1
(
  id integer NOT NULL,
  start_price integer NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT table1_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE table2
(
  id integer NOT NULL,
  end_price integer NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE result
(
  id integer NOT NULL,
  result_price decimal NOT NULL
);


INSERT INTO table1 VALUES (1, 140);
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES (2, 230);
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES (3, 70);
```

trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION delta_percent_calc() RETURNS TRIGGER AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO
        result(id,name)
        -- some logic here. seems that INSERT or UPDATE should be here because table1 and table2 price can be changed with update

           RETURN new;
END;
$BODY$
language plpgsql;
```

**UPD:**. it's seems that I get it work with follow solution:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION delta_percent_calc() RETURNS TRIGGER AS
$BODY$

 DECLARE
        s_price integer;
BEGIN

    select start_price into s_price from table1 where id = new.id;
    
    INSERT INTO 
        result (id,result_price)
          VALUES(new.id, round(100 - ( (new.end_price::numeric/s_price::numeric) * 100), 4 ) );
          ON CONFLICT (id) DO UPDATE
          SET result_price = round(100 - ( (new.end_price::numeric/s_price::numeric) * 100), 4 );

          RETURN new;
END;
$BODY$
language plpgsql;


CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trig_percent_calc
     AFTER INSERT ON table2
     FOR EACH ROW
     EXECUTE PROCEDURE delta_percent_calc();
```

Comment: 1)  [plpgsql trigger](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html) *Example 43.4. A PL/pgSQL Trigger Function for Auditing* will give layout for dealing with multiple operations. 2) You will need to `DECLARE` `s_price integer;` variable to hold `select start_price into s_price from table1 where id = new.id`. Then use `s_price` and `new.end_price` to do calculation saving it to another declared variable.

Comment: @Adrian Klaver
Thanks! It seems that I get it work. Could you check latest code from post?

Comment: 1) "seems that INSERT or UPDATE should be here because table1 and table2 price can be changed with update", so the trigger should be `AFTER  INSERT OR UPDATE`.  2) And then you need to use TG_OP = 'INSERT'/TG_OP = 'UPDATE' per the example I posted to differentiate the actions. 3) Also `IF FOUND` from here [Diagnostics](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-DIAGNOSTICS) to catch case where  `select start_price into s_price ..` does not fin anything.